# Select em duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, select

Tenho as tabelas autor e frase:

```
autor:
autor_id | autor_nome
1        | joão
2        | pedro

frase:
frase_id | frase_frases    |autor_id 
1        | frase do joão   | 1
2        | frase do pedro  | 2
3        | frase do pedro  | 2
4        | frase do pedro  | 2
```

Como faço para exibir o nome "pedro" e todas as "frase do pedro" ?

Tentei com inner join mas sem sucesso!

SELECT * FROM autor 
INNER JOIN frase
ON autor.autor_id = frase.autor_id

Comment: Tem uma linguagem de programação, ou só mesmo a SQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O que filtra o resultado por determinada condição é a cláusula `WHERE`.

Se quiser selecionar por nome:

```
SELECT
   autor.autor_nome,
   frase.frase_frases
FROM
   autor
INNER JOIN
   frase ON autor.autor_id = frase.autor_id
WHERE
   autor.autor_nome = 'pedro'
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8daf1/1)**.

Se quiser selecionar por `id`:

```
SELECT
   autor.autor_nome,
   frase.frase_frases
FROM
   autor
INNER JOIN
   frase ON autor.autor_id = frase.autor_id
WHERE
   autor.autor_id = 2
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8daf1/2)**.

Se preferir localizar por qualquer nome que tenha `pedro` no meio, pode usar assim:

```
WHERE
   autor.autor_nome LIKE '%pedro%'
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8daf1/3)**.

Lembrando que no MySQL o `INNER JOIN` é o mesmo que `CROSS JOIN`, aqui tem umas dicas sobre os possíveis usos do `JOIN`:

> [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/70)